# How to avoid inserting a duplicate into the SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

My application extracts data from my mailbox to `DataGrid` where I can manage them. I'm trying to avoid inserting a duplicate into the SQL Server database, but I'm getting an error when I return an object that is in the DB so I can compare it with the new one.

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the
> array.'

Method `GetById()` is same like `GetAlert()`, but it returns FK of different table (Problem).

Here I am getting new objects and their data, `Inbox.Count` returns
number of mails in mailbox:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
{
    var message = inbox.GetMessage(i, cancel.Token);
    GetBodyText = message.TextBody;
    Alert alert = new Alert(message.MessageId, message.Date.DateTime, message.From.ToString(), 1 , 1);

    if (dAOAlert.GetAlert(alert.Id_MimeMessage) != null)
    {
        dAOAlert.Save(alert);
        dAOProblem.Save(new Problem());
        alert.Problem_ID = dAOProblem.GetID(message.MessageId);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate");
    }
}
```

Method which returns object by `message_ID` of the mail:

```
public  Alert GetAlert(string message_ID)
{
    Alert alert = null;

    SqlConnection conn = DatabaseSingleton.GetInstance();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Alert] WHERE message_ID = @message_ID", conn))
    {
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@message_ID";
        param.Value = message_ID;

        command.Parameters.Add(param);

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // This loop throws exception
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            alert = new Alert
                    {
                        Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0].ToString()),
                        Id_MimeMessage = reader[1].ToString(),
                        Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[2].ToString()),
                        Email = reader[3].ToString(),
                        User_ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader[4].ToString()),
                        Problem_ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader[5].ToString())
                    };
        }

        reader.Close();

        return alert;
    }
}
```

> SQL Table Alert

**id , message_ID , date ,email,  AMUser_ID , Problem_ID**

Comment: `Problem_ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader[5].ToString())` <-- _ugh_

Comment: All of your database boilerplate code can and probably should be replaced by Dapper. This will also take care of mapping columns by names (not ordinals), and give you clear errors when this fails. Combining `SELECT *` with ordinal-based column access is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Dai What I am missing?

Comment: Use `Problem_ID = reader.GetInt32(5)` - much cleaner, much clearer and easier to understand - and less conversions involved .....

Comment: Maybe it would be better option to prevent inserting duplicates by sql command?

Comment: Still I have no idea, why I am getting the exception?

Comment: I would put good money on the thesis that the table `Alert` doesn't have the columns you think it does.

Comment: Error is occurring because some rows do not have 6 columns.  You need to test for null before reading each column.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, it does. I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I have made method, which returns `IEnumerable`, where I am checking if firstly empty and if `elemenent` exist in `IEnumerable`

```
 for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var message = inbox.GetMessage(i, cancel.Token);
                            GetBodyText = message.TextBody;
                        Problem problem = new Problem(message.MessageId);
                        if (!dAOProblem.GetAll().Any(x => x.Message_Id.Equals(problem.Message_Id)))
                        {
                            dAOProblem.Save(problem);
                            Alert alert = new Alert(message.MessageId, message.Date.DateTime, message.From.ToString(), 1, problem.Id);
                            if (!dAOAlert.GetAll().Any(x => x.Id_MimeMessage.Equals(alert.Id_MimeMessage)))
                            {
                                dAOAlert.Save(alert);

                            }
                          
                        }

                    }
```